# SQL: Filter on Alpha and numeric on column of Type TEXT

Tags: sql-server, alphanumeric

I've got a column of type Text.  In the column are numeric values such as`4, 8, 3.2, etc..`. and also values such as `'Negative', 'Positive', '27A', '2pos 1neg'.`

The user needs to be able to say: "Give me all the values between 10 and 30, and also the values that are 'Negative'.  The `WHERE` clause would need to do something along the lines of:

```
WHERE Tbl.Col > 10
AND   Tbl.Col < 30
AND   Tbl.Col = 'Negative'
```

This is problematic for obvious reasons.  I've tried using the ISNUMERIC function to alleviate the issue but can't seem to get exactly what i need.  I can either get all the alpha values in the column, or all the numeric values in the column as floats but cant seem to filter on both at the same time.  To grab all the Numeric values I've been using this:

```
SELECT Num.Val FROM 
    (SELECT Val = CASE ISNUMERIC(CAST(TBL.COL AS VARCHAR)) WHEN 1 
             THEN CAST(CAST(TBL.COL AS VARCHAR) AS FLOAT) ELSE NULL END
            FROM Table TBL
            WHERE TBL.COL IS NOT NULL ) as Num
    WHERE Num.val IS NOT NULL
    AND   Num.val > 10
```

Comment: When you say the column is "Text" do you mean it contains text or is it the text datatype? You could probably use a cte (or two) to capture the data you need. I will try to post something together but you didn't give us much to go on here.

Comment: @SeanLange It is of datatype 'Text'

Comment: Ugh!!! What version of sql server are you using? The text datatype has been deprecated since 2005. It is just awful to work with because you constantly have to cast to a usable datatype. If at all possible change to one of the varchar datatypes. You can change text to varchar(max) with no issue and you gain a lot of benefit. More then likely you could make it MUCH shorter. varchar(100) or something...that would depend on your actual data,

Comment: Heh I am honestly about to suggest to the designer of the Table that we split the column into two columns.  I believe this table among others were designed 10 or so years ago, so that's most likely why it is still type Text.  Also we are on SQL 2012.

Comment: It's 2014. Change your tables.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the issue correctly something like this should get you close.

```
with MyNumbers as
(
    select t.Col
    from Tbl t
    --where ISNUMERIC(t.Col) = 1
    where t.Col NOT LIKE '%[^0-9.]%'
)
, MyAlpha as
(
    select t.Col
    from Tbl t
    where ISNUMERIC(t.Col) = 0
)

select Col
from MyNumbers
where Col > 10
    and Col < 30

union all

select Col
from MyAlpha
where ColorMatch = ' Negative'
```

Comment: Interesting solution.  Still, I'm getting the type clash errors.  I'm going to go ahead and get with the table designer and split the column into two separate columns for numeric/alpha values.  Thanks for the help though everyone.

Comment: The type clash errors are almost certainly due to the fact that ISNUMERIC is pretty useless. It should be named IsValueSomethingThatCanLooselyBeConvertedToAnyExistingDatatypeThatContainsAnySortOfNumber. In other words you have some values like '$1.00' or '1e4' that IsNumeric will evaluate to true but is not an actual number.

Comment: I changed the where predicate in the first cte so it will more accurately find actual numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

First I would go slap the person who designed the table (hopefully it isn't you) :>

Go to [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020153409/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/031004-1.shtml) and get the split table function.  I would then convert the text column (like you have in example above) into varchar(max) and supply it as the parameter to the split function.  Then you could select from the table results of the split function using the user supplied parameters.

Comment: I would recommend checking out this article. Using a while loop for a splitter is the slowest way of all the possibilities available. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: Also, I don't think the OP has multiple values in a single column, they have some rows with "numeric" strings and they want to search both numeric and strings in the same logic.

Comment: @SeanLange Yes that's correct, I have some rows with numeric values, some rows with string values, and some rows with alphanumeric values.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to my problem:

```
SELECT
al_Value   =    Table.Column
FROM Table
WHERE ( 
        ISNUMERIC(CAST(Table.Column AS VARCHAR)) = 1 AND 
        CONVERT(FLOAT, CAST(Table.Column AS VARCHAR)) > 1.0 AND 
        CONVERT(FLOAT, CAST(Table.Column AS VARCHAR)) < 10.0
      )    
OR    ( 
        CAST(Table.Column AS VARCHAR) IN ('negative', 'no bueno') 
      )
```

This will return one column named 'al_Value' that filters on Table.Column (which is of Datatype TEXT) and apply the filters in the WHERE clause above.

Thanks everyone for trying to help me with this issue.